# How to install pulseaudio 5 on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

Guys how i can install pulseaudio 5? i don't understand the installation step on this link
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/pulseaudio.html

anybody can tell me how to install it ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a bit old to install PulseAudio 5, even 14.04 will ship PulseAudio 4, see the dedicated [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/pulseaudio).

If you really need the latest version, I would rely on the PulseAudio [testing ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/pulse-testing), which provides a properly packaged version of PulseAudio 5 for 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/pulse-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

Well every thing is described well on the link you've provided. If I am right, You would not be able to understand the commands and the steps written there. You have to follow the same step and there is no other way. I can help you to just understand what is going there. :)

1. The file which you can download [from here](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/releases/pulseaudio-5.0.tar.xz) is nothing but the source file which you can compile, make and install in any system. same you've to do in your system. So the **Package Information** section will give you the source file.
2. **PulseAudio Dependencies**: section tells you about the packages which will be required by **PulseAudio5**. **Required** and **Recommended** packages are necessary and you've to install them first before you can install **PulseAudio5**. Though you can neglect **Optional** packages.
3. **Installation of PulseAudio**: section tells you the actual command that you've to execute in order to install PulseAudio. So don't worry of them, just copy and paste it in your terminal. Be sure that you've installed successfully packages **PulseAudio Dependencies** section.
4. **Command Explanation**: section gives you a short description of the commands that you're going to execute.

That's it. Reply if you need further assistance..